# soap response empty ios

Tags: ios, soap, response, nsdata

i am sending a soap request. But no data is being returned. The web service does not return any error. I am unable to figure out what is wrong. Does it have something to do with the UTF8 Encoding? Please help. Below is my code:

```
NSString *xmlString = @"<ServiceCalls xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><ServiceCall><Phone_No>033542390843</Phone_No></ServiceCall></ServiceCalls>";

                NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                        "<soap:Body>\n"
                        "<GetVehiclesByPhone_ServiceCall_Proc xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                        "<xmlStr>%@</xmlStr>\n"
                        "<m_LoginId>Username</m_LoginId>\n"
                        "<m_pass>Password</m_pass>\n"
                        "</GetVehiclesByPhone_ServiceCall_Proc>\n"
                        "</soap:Body>\n"
                        "</soap:Envelope>", xmlString];

                NSLog(@"%@", soapMessage);

                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://103.9.23.21/TPL_Web_Services/TPLInterface.asmx"];
                NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

                [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/GetVehiclesByPhone_ServiceCall_Proc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
                [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                NSURLResponse *response;
                NSError *error;
                NSData *webData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

                if (webData != nil) {
                    NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Data: %@", data);
                    if (error == nil) {
                        if ([data isEqualToString:@"True"] || [data isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
                            [self showSuccessfulAlert];
                            [self storeDefaults];
                            [self.dataLayer notifySplashRemoved];
                        }
                        else {
                            /*UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Data!" message:@"The phone no. you entered is not registered." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                            [alert show];*/
                            sendSMS = YES;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        sendSMS = YES;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    sendSMS = YES;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Content-Length` properly: the content length is the length of the body data in bytes, not the length of the NSString, which is the number of UTF-16 code units:

```
NSData* body = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* bodyLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body count]];
[theRequest addValue: bodyLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:body];
...
```

Comment: You should now switch to an approach with `NSURLConnection` implementing delegates. This enables you to debug much more thoroughly and figure out possible issues. NSLog as much as you can - especially result codes and *HTTP response code* and any *HTTP response body*. Generously sprinkle assertion macros into your code, and step through.

Comment: tried that as well. i am getting data as empty in the didfinishloading.

Comment: Is `webData` nil, or empty (that is, it is not `nil`, but its length is zero)? If it's nil, you should print the error and edit your post in order to provide this essential info.

Comment: webData is not nil. I get "<>" in webData.